# Connecting to Amazon rds with Python

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

Using MySQL Workbench, I can connect mysql running on amazon rds. I supply SSH Hostname, SSH Username, SSH Password, SSH Key File, MySQL Hostname, MySQL Server Port, Username, and Password.

However, I have a python script with which I'd like to connect to this same database. I tried using ssh tunneling:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (SSH Hostname, 22),
        ssh_password=SSH Password,
        ssh_username=SSH Username,
        ssh_pkey= SSH Key File path,
        remote_bind_address=(MySQL Hostname, MySQL Port) as server:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            host = MySQL Hostname,
            port = MySQL Port,
            user = Username,
            passwd = Password)
```

When I run the script, it hangs for about a minute, then says 
'Can't connect to MySQL server on ~MySQL Hostname~'

I am unsure about the remote_bind_address. Since I don't supply that info when successfully connecting from MySQLWorkbench, is there a way to connect from Python without specifying remote_bind_address?

Additionally, I tried using the scripting tool in MySQL Workbench. I am able to load my python script, but then an error occurs at one of my imports, specifically 'import module requests'. The error indicates there is no module named requests. However, this module has been installed for a while, and I have imported and successfully used it outside of MySQL Workbench.

Comment: I do not have much experience with python, but connecting to any MySQL should requires only the MySQL server IP, port, username and password, nothing else. Is that SSHTunnelForwarder thing necessary?